# Running socket.io on Hostmonster's shared servers

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, websocket, socket.io

I am planning a little hobby project that will use node on Hostmonster. Now, I know Hostmonster is meant for Apache, but I figured a way to run node.js continually using [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) and manually compiling node. So, simple restAPI requests work.

I.e.,

1. I run a node server on localhost:3000
2. I have a link on the server `//relay.example.com/r.php?arg1=val`
3. GET requests that come into that URL are funneled as such

> ```
> $fp = fsockopen("localhost", 3001, $errno, $errstr, 5);
>
> if (!$fp) {
>   echo "Error: $errno - $errstr";
> } else {
>   $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
>   $out .= "Host: localhost\r\n";
>   $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
>   fwrite($fp, $out);
>   while (!feof($fp)) {
>     echo fgets($fp, 128);
>   }
>   fclose($fp);
> }
> ```

4. Node /express pick up the request and sends a response back via `res.send`

However, I would much rather use Websockets! To do that, I need to figure a way to route incoming requests (GET/POST) into socket.io and then have them route back to the client. I don't think I can reconfigure apache (and thus try something like [ProxyPass](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1696), as that is not installed on hostmonster -- or I can't find it if it is labeled something else.

At the moment, I am using a [php relay script (fsockopen)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) to route incoming requests to the local node process and using echo to send the information back to the requester. Not very pretty but it works.

I imagine a system that works with socket.IO would ideally rely on `.htaccess` to route websocket requests to my local node process on its local port.

I simply just don't know how to figure/hack my way through Hostmonster to do that!

Comment: Are you able to contact the node server running on port 3000 externally, or is it firewalled by hostmaster?

Comment: It is firewalled though I suspect it could work if I bought my own IP address, however I would rather funnel everything through standard ports anyway, such as 80 or 443

Comment: The problem with your approach is that you are doing a request and then a response, while a websocket is continuously sending and receiving data. I'm unsure if you can proxy websockets at all with Apache and php.

Comment: I wonder if I could use something like this https://github.com/jenssegers/php-proxy and funnel from 0.0.0.0:80 <--> localhost:3000 ?

Comment: You can run socket.io on your host, without using the websockets capabilities. If you only have apache facing out, and no access to install apache modules, I think this is your best bet.